# the windows API does not work with python3 but works with python 2

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have a python script that I'm trying to convert from python 2.7 to python 3.7. 
The script includes windows API to read the system registry. In python 2.7 it works correctly. In python 3.7 it does not return the correct result.

I try to run the script python 3 in another PC with python 3. I run the script only in powershell like administrator.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa this is the documentation of RegOpenKeyExA() function.
In python 2.7 I installed "VCForPython27.msi" from: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi which for windows 3.7 I don't find a updated version.

```
from ctypes import c_uint, c_char_p, byref, windll
subkey = 'JD'    

def RegOpenKeyEx(subkey):
        hkey = c_uint(0) ## Initialize to an int
        windll.advapi32.RegOpenKeyExA(0x80000002, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa\\' + subkey, 0, 0xF003F , byref(hkey))
        print(hkey.value)
        return hkey.value
```

In python 2.7 the output is:
656
and the windll.advapi32.RegOpenKeyExA function returns 0 as a return value.

In python 3.7 the output is:
0
and the windll.advapi32.RegOpenKeyExA function returns 2 as a return value

Comment: What documentation did you read? Your issue could be a whole system issue, not one tied to your program. And please give some [MCVE]

Comment: 2 is a "not found" error code

Comment: Use the standard library's winreg module (or _winreg in 2.x), which is a much safer and more efficient C extension.

Comment: This ctypes code uses a wrong type (a handle is not an `unsigned int`; it's a `void *`; as it happens, non-negative kernel handles are in a 32-bit range, and the special negative values will be sign extended to 64-bit given ctypes default `c_int` argument conversion), dubious values (luckily ctypes by default sign extends 0x80000002), legacy ANSI (the registry is Unicode), and relies on `windll` instead of `WinDLL("advapi32", use_last_error=True)`. Global `windll` has problems with last error handling and inconsistent prototyping with other libraries that use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with replace the 6th row with:

```
windll.advapi32.RegOpenKeyExA(0x80000002, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa\\'.encode('ascii') + subkey.encode('ascii'), 0, 0x19 , byref(hkey))
```

In Python 2.7, strings are byte-strings by default. In Python 3.x, they are unicode by default. I explicitly making string a byte string using .encode('ascii').

Comment: Switching to `RegOpenKeyExW` and explicitly setting the `argtypes`  (so it knows to convert to a `LPWSTR`) should also work, would support non-ASCII names, and wouldn't require explicitly encoding at each point of use.